# Java WebService is not "visible" in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

I have developed a simple webservice in Eclipse/Apache Axis 1.4 (Created simple methods in java, generated WSDL, generated java classes from WSDL - all in/using Eclipse) and it seems to deploy *ok* locally in Tomcat. However, when I export to a .WAR file to deploy to a Weblogic server (which deploys without any errors) the actual webservice doesn't seem to be displayed.

Going to /services displays only the two below.

```
And now... Some Services

AdminService (wsdl)
AdminService
Version (wsdl)
getVersion
```

I believe there might be an error in server-config.wsdd, but it was auto-generated and I can't seem to see anything wrong with it.

```
<ns1:deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/">
 <ns1:globalConfiguration>
  <ns1:parameter name="sendMultiRefs" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="disablePrettyXML" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="adminPassword" value="admin"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="dotNetSoapEncFix" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="enableNamespacePrefixOptimization" value="false"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="sendXMLDeclaration" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="sendXsiTypes" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="attachments.implementation" value="org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl"/>
  <ns1:requestFlow>
   <ns1:handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
    <ns1:parameter name="scope" value="session"/>
   </ns1:handler>
   <ns1:handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
    <ns1:parameter name="scope" value="request"/>
    <ns1:parameter name="extension" value=".jwr"/>
   </ns1:handler>
  </ns1:requestFlow>
 </ns1:globalConfiguration>
 <ns1:handler name="URLMapper" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper"/>
 <ns1:handler name="LocalResponder" type="java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalResponder"/>
 <ns1:handler name="Authenticate" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.SimpleAuthenticationHandler"/>
 <ns1:service name="DomainManagement" provider="java:RPC" style="wrapped" use="literal">
  <ns1:parameter name="allowedMethods" value="*"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="typeMappingVersion" value="1.2"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlPortType" value="DomainManagement"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="className" value="com.DomainManagement.DomainManagementSoapBindingImpl"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlServicePort" value="DomainManagement"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="schemaQualified" value="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap,http://DomainManagement.com"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlTargetNamespace" value="http://DomainManagement.com"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlServiceElement" value="DomainManagementService"/>
  <ns2:typeMapping deserializer="org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializerFactory" encodingStyle="" qname="ns1:Domain" serializer="org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializerFactory" type="java:com.DomainManagement.Domain" xmlns:ns1="http://DomainManagement.com" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"/>
 </ns1:service>
 <ns1:service name="AdminService" provider="java:MSG">
  <ns1:parameter name="allowedMethods" value="AdminService"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="enableRemoteAdmin" value="false"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="className" value="org.apache.axis.utils.Admin"/>
  <ns1:namespace>http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/</ns1:namespace>
 </ns1:service>
 <ns1:service name="Version" provider="java:RPC">
  <ns1:parameter name="allowedMethods" value="getVersion"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="className" value="org.apache.axis.Version"/>
 </ns1:service>
 <ns1:transport name="http">
  <ns1:requestFlow>
   <ns1:handler type="URLMapper"/>
   <ns1:handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler"/>
  </ns1:requestFlow>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs:list" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSListHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs:wsdl" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs.list" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSListHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs.method" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSMethodHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs:method" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSMethodHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs.wsdl" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler"/>
 </ns1:transport>
 <ns1:transport name="local">
  <ns1:responseFlow>
   <ns1:handler type="LocalResponder"/>
  </ns1:responseFlow>
 </ns1:transport>
</ns1:deployment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a Java Mis-match. Webservice was compiled using 1.7 (51/7) however server only supported 1.6 (50/6).

There was no error when deploying it (which in my opinion there should be), however digging into the logs i found it.